# How to get rid of "BSCMAKE : error BK1500: Internal error" compile errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I use msbuild to compile a **Visual Studio 2010** solution and need a successful build without any errors.

But each time I run msbuild, or rebuild, or clean and compile my solution directly using Visual Studio, I get several bscmake errors like this one. Sometimes the errors disappear when compiling again without cleaning, but it is not a good solution to me to run msbuild twice.

```
[...]
10>  Generating Code...
11>  xxxxxxxx\mshtml.tlh(63588): warning BK4504: file contains too many references; ignoring further references from this source
11>  
11>BSCMAKE : error BK1500: Internal error
11>  
11>    Version 10.00.30319.01
11>  
11>    ExceptionCode            = C0000005
11>    ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
11>    ExceptionAddress         = 001343DA (00130000) "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\bscmake.exe"
11>    NumberParameters         = 00000002
11>    ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
11>    ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 00000000
11>  
11>  CONTEXT:
11>    Eax    = 00141B30  Esp    = 003CF1C0
11>    Ebx    = 04B142C6  Ebp    = 003CF770
11>    Ecx    = 04BB621C  Esi    = 00000006
11>    Edx    = 00000000  Edi    = 00000001
11>    Eip    = 001343DA  EFlags = 00010293
11>    SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
11>    SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
11>    SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
11>    Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
11>    Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
11>    Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000

[...]
```

The point is that I don't need browse information for my release and I don't want this error message to occur. It was possible to hide errors like these with Visual Studio 2008, but I think that the compiler parameter is no longer available.

**How can I hide bscmake errors?**

**Can I deactivate bscmake (for release versions)?**

Comment: Just turn the option off, it is entirely useless these days anyway.  C/C++, Browse Information, Enable = None.

Comment: Agree browse information is not required and can cause build errors when your solution tries to write the browse files, it also adds to build times so I would turn it off

Comment: @HansPassant: Could you provide more information? You say “it is entirely useless these days anyway” — so what fulfils the same function now?

Comment: Actually, Browse information is still used these days.  Such as ARCHITECTURE->Generate Dependency Graph.

Comment: @PJTraill: See here to understand purpose of "Browse Information". It looks that its sucessor is "intellisense daemon". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565516/what-is-the-purpose-of-browse-information-generated-by-visual-studio

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Hans Passants comment:

[image]

Thank's!

Comment: In addition to the "Enable Browse Information" on a per-project basis, there is an "Enable Browse Information" option on each of your source files. If CL.EXE still creates the .SBR files, set that property to "No" under the propertied for each source file. This option can get set during conversion from an older Visual Studio Project.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Hans Passant says “it is entirely useless these days anyway” — so what fulfils the same function now?

Comment: I think the the proposed solution solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: @PJTraill "Although BSCMAKE is still installed with Visual Studio, it is no longer used by the IDE. Since Visual Studio 2008, browse and symbol information is stored automatically in a SQL Server .sdf file in the solution folder." See: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/build/reference/bscmake-reference

Comment: @Carsten: Thanks for the reference. I conclude from it that it is conceivable (but pretty unlikely by now) that one might want to generate the **.sbr** and **.bsc** files for use by some third-party tool, but that there is indeed no other good reason.

Comment: @PJTraill: Exactly. Interestingly, the [Code Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/modeling/use-code-maps-to-debug-your-applications) feature somehow requires the `/FR` switch to be enabled. But is the only tool within VS that I know, that still uses browse info.

Answer (score 1):

One cause of this is to have a .cpp file compiled with /clr in a project with an output of a static lib. Either remove the /clr from the file or change the project to output a dll.