# Is bscmake needed using Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering **if bscmake is still needed for Visual Studio 2010 C++ Projects** using unmamanged/managed code.

My understanding of bscmake is, that it is generating browse-files for each cpp-file in order to be able to use things in visual studio like the "class view" or "go to definition",...

But after asking a question about bscmake myself and reading other similar questions I was unsure what bscmake is for and why you should use it.
References:

- [How to get rid off “BSCMAKE error BK1500: Internal error” compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228627/how-to-get-rid-off-bscmake-error-bk1500-internal-error-compile-errors)
- [LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during BuildLibrary](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/642900/linker-access-violation-link-fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-buildlibrary)

[image: Turn bscmake off]

So my question is:

- **Is there any need to activate bscmake?**
- **Advantages/Disadvantages activating bscmake?**

Comment: It was used by tooling a long time ago.  Previous century.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intellisense does not need the browse information, it is used for object explorer which I have never used or needed to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbs280h1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The main disadvantages are longer builds, build errors due to being unable to build the bsc files.

The main advantages are you can view more information of your classes and objects and apparently they have added some feature called 'live browsing' since VS2005 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163658.aspx.

However I have to say that the intellisense has worked fine for me, plus I use VisualAssist and I have never needed the object browser and find that the additional compilation time and build errors is so frustrating for large solutions that I never have this switch on.

Answer (score 9):

bscmake seems no longer be supported for VS2010, see this bug reports:
[Per-project Browsing in VS2010](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646058/per-project-browsing-in-vs2010) and [BSC files cannot be used](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514470/bsc-files-cannot-be-used).
So you can speed up your compile times by turning off the creation of SBR/BSC files,
as they are useless anyway.

BSC files had the big advantage that they could be used to browse external libraries which
were not part of your solution (MFC for example). This seems not be possible with
intellisense. I personally use VisualAssist as a replacement (which works quite well for me).

Comment: Microsoft answer posted here might also be useful https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595752/bk1505-error-during-c-build