# How to define a pre-build/pre-compile step in Visual Studio 2010, that runs every time?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

The task is to disblay the current subversion revision number in a mfc program. My idea is to create a rev.h file on every compile/build/run with a define. I get the rev from  svnversion.

So far, so good. It works.
The problem is I can't find a Event/Step, that works every time.

At first I tried it with a Pre-Build Event in the projects settings. It works the first time but the next time in rebuild the project it will cause the infamous SBR error. I rebuild again and the BSCMAKE error happens. Next time it is the SBR error again and so on.

The next thing I tried are those Custom Build Steps (Execute Before: CICompile/Build/Run ...). It works the first thime again but this steps will be skipped by VS if there are no changes. Since rev.h is not versioned, a commit changes the rev but not the files of the project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, I foun a solution in another thread:
[How to get rid off "BSCMAKE error BK1500: Internal error" compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228627/how-to-get-rid-off-bscmake-error-bk1500-internal-error-compile-errors)

This solved the bscmake error and it works for me.