# Failed to locate bscmake.exe -during linux compilation only

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I have a project written in C# and C++ and I want it to run on windows and linux . Therefore, I'm using .NET Core, for the cross-platforming.

When I try to compile the project in Windows, everything works fine.
But when I try to compile it  in the Linux environment(Ubuntu 16.04), using SSH port to a different linux computer(which has openssh-server+curl+unzip, according to some link to compilation I got...) , it raises the following error:

### Failed to locate bscmake.exe

Even though it worked well when I had Ubuntu 14.04 before I upgraded to 16.04
Did I forget to download some package in linux?
Searches all over the internet have nothing to do with my case...
Does anyone here know why this error is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:
[How to get rid off "BSCMAKE error BK1500: Internal error" compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228627/how-to-get-rid-off-bscmake-error-bk1500-internal-error-compile-errors)

we need to get rid of "Enable Browse Information".
In VS 2015's case:

right-click on project.vcsproj, and replacing:
**true**

into

**false**

on the "Enable_Browse" attr.